# Large items in the notification area (AKA system tray)?

Tags: .net, windows-xp, taskbar, system-tray, trayicon

I would like to place some large items in the XP system tray. (the one next to the clock)

By this i mean items that take up more than the standard icon space.

I know it can be done because I have seen several weather and time applications with this functionality.

For example http://www.respectsoft.com/weather-clock-screenshots.php (see the clock screen shots)

But I cannot find any doco on how to do this.

While .net code would be preferred instructions in other technologies would also be helpful.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: I think you mean the system tray area which is different than the taskbar which contains the start button, quick launch icons, task icons and system tray.

Comment: Thanks JB. I have made a couple of edits based on your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the only thing that can go in the system tray that is larger than an icon is the clock.  There are dozens of applications that replace the standard clock, including at least one open source option from which you may be able to take some relevant code.

[WinCalendartime](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincalendartime/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use Band Objects. You won't be using system tray, however you'll get the feature you need (that I guess is something like Windows Quick Launch or Windows Media Player).

Here's a good article about it. I'm studying it right now. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx?msg=3230393#xx3230393xx

[]'s