# Clock Gadget in taskbar using C#

Tags: c#, taskbar, windows-desktop-gadgets

How can I add my clock gadget using C# like in below image

[image: Clock Image]

I am making clock in Windows Form using C#.

**How can I place my clock in taskbar and at the place where time is displayed in Notification area?**

**Update:**
Is this can be done by `notifyIcon` ?

Comment: +1 for [not calling it a "system tray"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx).

Comment: Related to ".Net Large items in the Notification Area" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632568/large-items-in-the-notification-area-aka-system-tray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poking around with Spy++ (installed by default with Visual Studio) you will find that the name of this window is TrayClockWClass.  You can then get a handle to it with some basic Pinvoke calls outlined in this blog post:

http://vladimir-kurka.blogspot.com/2009/09/using-pinvoke.html

If what you are attempting is possible this should at least point you in the right direction.